# Why can't I utilize other model objects in my custom Manager?

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a custom `django.db.models.manager.Manager` (let's call it `MyManager`) for `MyModel`.

The methods in `MyManager` needs to invoke filter methods on `AnotherModel`.

Is this possible ? I'm getting an `ImportError` because of this.

Comment: Show us the code, and the error with full traceback.

Comment: The right solution is to add a custom manager for both models.

Comment: Moving aside that it might not be the best practice. It should work. Please show the code and stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

In your `MyModel`, you need to add your `MyManager` as an explicit manager.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
```

You can retain the standard Manager and have your manager both, by including this manager by another name.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myobjects = MyManager()
```

If you are using the django-admin, there are nuances involved in what manager's objects are picked up. You can find those and many other details from the [awesome django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).